# Problemas con id en script

Tags: javascript

tengo este input

```
@foreach (var j in jornada){
<input id="jor" name="NombrJornada" type="radio" value="@j.IdJornada" onclick="Filtro"/>
}
```

y mi script tengo esto

```
$(function() {
        $("#jor").click(function () {
            console.log("Hola");
        });
    });
```

El problema es que mi script solo se ejecuta en un solo radio button podrían ayudarme a resolver este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reemplaza en tu HTML:

```
<input id="jor" name="NombrJornada" type="radio" value="@j.IdJornada" onclick="Filtro"/>
```

Por:

```
<input class="jor" name="NombrJornada" type="radio" value="@j.IdJornada" onclick="Filtro"/>
```

y en tu JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
            $("#jor").click(function () {
                console.log("Hola");
            });
});
```

Por:

```
$(function() {
            $(".jor").click(function () {
                console.log("Hola");
            });
});
```

Explicación:

Sólo se puede tener 1 solo ID para 1 elemento, en caso múltiples elementos tengan el mismo ID, los eventos escucha (event listeners) funcionarán sólo en 1. 
Puedes tener múltiples clases, el selector de jQuery utiliza un punto en lugar de un michi (#).

Comment: Muchas gracias! me funciono de maravilla.

Comment: de nada hermano, éxitos con el desarrollo de software, bienvenido a bordo :D